# Style a span to use 100% height of a list item

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to display a series of name value pairs where the span items is floated left and takes 100% of the height of the parent `<li>` element. (Creates a left column.)

I know that if I set a fixed height for the `<li>`, it works. However, I wanted the `<li>` content to determine the height to support content line wrapping.

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aRXet/

```html
        <ul>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
            <li><span>Name</span>Value</li>
        </ul>
```

```css
  li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #7492a1;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: emCalc(12px);
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    height:100%;
    clear: both;
    float: left;

  }

  li span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #888f99;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: emCalc(62px);
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: It is 100%. Any space that is present is due to the `margin` and `padding` you have set.

Comment: did any of the answers help you ? please vote up and mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the `li` has padding and margin. Especially the margin is the cause of the 5px white space. Remove the padding and margin from the `li` to solve the problem. Add any padding to the `span` if you want more space between the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/aRXet/2/

```
 li {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      ....
  }
  li span {
      margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
      padding: 0 10px;
      ....
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set your padding and margin to 0 you will see that the span is 100%

```
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/aRXet/4/

To get the effect you want set a height and a line height

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/aRXet/5/

```
li {
    // other css
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by setting the position of span element to `absolute position` with some js stuff to adjust its parent `li` element height.

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 110px; //SPAN WIDTH + 10px ~ li's PADDING
}

li span{
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;

  color: #000;
  width: 100px; //MAX SPAN WIDTH
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Adjusting `li` **height** (using jQuery)

```
$("ul li span").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > $(this).parent().height() ) {
    $(this).parent().height($(this).height());
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wikiziner/b8cZW/)